# Перемещение объектов в рабочий поток

Tags: qt5

Если создать рабочий поток в довесок к главному и переместить в него некий объект некоего класса, а этот перемещенный объект создаст в свою очередь другой объект другого  класса, то в каком потоке будет этот второй объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет в потоке своего "создателя"

Comment: Можно пруф? Я не нашёл где бы это упоминалось

Comment: @DowJhob, если попробуете создать объект `QObject` (о них ведь речь?), родитель которого живёт в ином потоке, то сразу в консоль выведется предупреждение от Qt.

Comment: У вторичного объекта в другом потоке не указывается родитель, я его в деструкторе первичного объекта удаляю.